# How can I post array keys that have special characters?

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have a form that contains some special characters as the keys. 
 Below is an example:

```
<input type="text" name="skills[React.js]" placeholder="Years" class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="skills[Responsive-Web-Design-(RWD)]" placeholder="Years" class="form-control">
```

When I post the form I get 0:value, 1:value
Instead of React.js:value, Responsive-Web-Design-(RWD): value

Are there any workarounds?

Comment: where are you passing value ?? and how are you retrieving them ? post that part of th code as well

Comment: A `var_dump`  of the request variables should show you that. It is also explained in the PHP manual how input names are converted into keys of the request variables in the PHP manual: [Variables From External Sources](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php)

Comment: Try it and see if it works. The browser should handle encoding those keys for transit, and PHP should then decode them on the other end.

Answer (score 0):

To get desired output, text input should be like this

```
<input type="text" name="skills[]"  
 placeholder="Years" class="form-control"
 value="React.js"> 

 <input type="text" name="skills[]"   
  placeholder="Years" class="form-control"
  value="Responsive-Web-Design-(RWD)">
```

And in server side, received these values

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['skills'])){
      $value1=$_POST['skills'][0];
      $value2=$_POST['skills'][1];
     }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could do it using vanilla PHP

```
<?php

$topics = [
    1 => 'React.js',
    2 => 'Responsive-Web-Design-(RWD)'
]

?>

<?php foreach ($topics as $key => $label) { ?>
    <input type="text" name="skills[<?php echo $key; ?>]" placeholder="Years" class="form-control">
<?php } ?>
```

The submitted request should contain:

```
[
    'skills' => [
        1 => 'first field value',
        2 => 'second field value',
    ]
]
```

So to get it the way you want it:

```
$skills = [];

foreach($_POST['skills'] as $key => $value) {
    $skills[$topics[$key]] = $value;
}
```

the `$result` array would now contain:

```
[
    'React.js' => 'value 1',
    'Responsive-Web-Design-(RWD)' => 'value 2'
]
```